# Previous GCP service account being used when deploying Firebase Functions despite passing updated service account info to admin.initializeApp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli, google-iam

I am switching my Firebase functions from one Firebase account to another.
I have rerun `firebase init`.
I have added the new service account configs to the project and am passing it to `admin.initializeApp`. I have logged into GCP via my CLI and have run `firebase login:ci` as well.

Despite all this, whenever I try to run `firebase deploy`, I am met with the error:

> Missing permissions required for functions deploy. You must have permission iam.serviceAccounts.ActAs on service account @appspot.gserviceaccount.com.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with the service account you use to initialize the Firebase Admin SDK.  The error has to do with the lack of permission of the Google Account that you used to sign in with the Firebase CLI.  It doesn't have permission to deploy to Cloud Functions.  You should either sign out then sign back in with an account that has permission (typically "editor" role), or add the appropriate permission to the account that you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - but I have the admin role with the account I signed into the Firebase CLI with and am still getting this error.  Somehow my Firebase Functions are referencing an old service account and I'm not sure where or how to change it.

Comment: I really don't think this has anything to do with the service account that you use for init.  The message is clear that there is a missing permission for **deploy**, and it's even telling you which specific permission is missing.  The code isn't even being run yet.

Comment: The error message is referencing `serviceAccount A`.  
This was the old account I was working with.  I have removed all reference to `serviceAccount A` as I am migrating to `serviceAccount B`.  And yet it is still referencing `serviceAccount A`.
Maybe it doesn't have anything to do with the with the account used for init.  I am just wanting to know how to point my project to the new service account instead of the old one.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're going to have to double check the permissions on the account you used to sign in with the Firebase CLI and make sure it has the stated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're migrating to a new Firebase project / account, you must delete the project's existing .firebaserc and firebase.json files before running `firebase init` - this will ensure that you're using the updated project configs.